# Mocking ANY class use in Java (specifically in Android)

Tags: c#, java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I am coming from the .NET world (C#) to Java (Android development).

Many mocking frameworks and tools from the .NET space allow replacing/overriding class/method usage without injecting any mock objects into tested methods  ([Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) is one).

For example, in the following method:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
     new SomeOtherClass().Do("This is a test!");
}
```

Calling the **SomeOtherClass().Do** method can be made to return a specific value or to behave in a certain manner, even though i have not injected a mock object for this class into this method.

Using **Microsoft Fakes** for example, this can be done by code simliar to this:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
      // decide what to do when Do() gets called
      System.Fakes.ShimSomeOtherClass.Do = str => ....

      new SomeOtherClass().Do("blabla");
}
```

As far as i've seen in the Java/Android mocking world, doing something like that is impossible. I would have to refactor all my code to inject its dependencies for every method.

While this may be a good practice indeed in some places, it would be impossible to do in all code locations.

Is there any way to achieve this with Java?

Frameworks i'm working with: Mockito, PowerMock, Robolectric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the instantiation of a new object with PowerMock using `expectNew()`

http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

```
SomeOtherClass someOtherMock = createMock(SomeOtherClass.class);
expectNew(SomeOtherClass.class).andReturn(someOtherMock);
expect(someOtherMock.do("blabla")).andReturn(...);
```

Edit: You can use with Mockito with the PowerMockito extensions

http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(SomeOtherClass.class)...
```

Comment: This all fits well except the last line. I don't necessarily want to assert against someOtherMock, but i do want to be able to have it return canned values to the method that uses it. Seems to do what i want. Testing it :)

Comment: This example seems to be for EasyMock. I need something that will work for Mockito

Comment: I've never used them, but I think PowerMock comes with extensions for Mockito http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Mockito does what you are asking, here's some of my test code:

```
SnapshotManager snapshotManager = mock(SnapshotManager.class);
when(snapshotManager.storeBroadcast("MessageURL1", "B1")).thenReturn(new Distribution("AltMessageURL1", 1));
```

The syntax is more complex, but the behaviour is the same.

The String literals in the storeBroadcast method do not need to be Strings they can be set to constrain values too.

Plus you have the option to spy on values and to verify the expected methods were called after you injected the instance into your code.

Comment: Sorry but this is not really related to what i asked.